# Android Studio button method works only one time

Tags: java, android, button

I have an activity which onCreate starts a listener for a button onclick, as below:

```
    buttonCal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCal);
    buttonCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            calAge();
        }
    });
```

The code then do puts some text into a textview.

```
    TextView txtAGE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAGE);
    txttxtAGE.setText(strAGE);
```

The code work fine, once. I have tried putting the listener code below the setText() function and it still doesn't work. Does anybody know why? or how I can get it so the button can be pressed an infinite amount of time and calculate a new age and display it in textview?

thanks for any help :)

Comment: Show your full calAge() method.

Comment: The error is most likely to do with your calAge() method with values not passing, please post it.

Comment: You think 25 is old?

Comment: Does the value of `Age` change between clicks? If not, the method `calAge` won't appear to do anything the second time.

Comment: Age is a number typed in a textbox. i change age each time so i should get a new value, and no i dont hahah else im pretty old myself

Comment: It looks like `Age` isn't changing. Can you also post where you declare, assign and modify `Age`?

Comment: Change `txtYourAge.setText(strYourAge);` to `txtYourAge.setText("" + new Random().nextInt());`. That will tell you if the problem is with `Age`.

Comment: When and where you set the value for `strAGE`?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what code you are trying to execute when the button is pressed. You've got the **onClick** property set in your **xml** file to a method called Button_Click.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="Button_Click"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Now in your Java Class

```
  public void Button_Click(View i)
{
  //do your code

}
```

Comment: This won't fix the issue if the problem is caused by the logic code inside the listener, not the listener itself. I believe the listener is called fine.